# openbsd, mc, console

Tags: консоль, mc, openbsd

в mc под линами при ctrl-o есть возможность не просто видеть консоль, но и выполнять в ней команды. как добиться этого в опёнке? конкретно речь про удалённо через putty(xterm в линах и опёнке, но такое разное поведение, так что вряд ли это связано с терминалом)

Answer (score 0):

в current добавили такую возможность для дефолтной ksh(это зависит от шелла, с тем же bash работало и раньше)